# how i can place the button below a list

Tags: android, android-listview

I try place the button below a List, but the button does not appear.

I use RelativeLayout.

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Lista"
        >
         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listFotMultas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_below="@+id/Lista"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Total Fotomulta"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/estilo_redondoboton"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, delete the property **layout_below** in my button

```
android:layout_below="@+id/Lista"
```

Add the property in my button **layout_alignParentBottom**

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

And add the property **layout_marginBottom** in my relative @+id/Lista

```
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

[image]

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/ListaEncabezado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/Lista"
        >
         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listFotMultas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

            <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Total Fotomulta"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/estilo_redondoboton"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Using below layout u can also have button visible :-
[NOTE:- this suggestion is given for the reason if you want to use linearlayout instead of relative layout you can try this way ]

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listFotMultas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:text="Total Fotomulta" />
```

THANKS!~!